# Regular Expressions: Any set of characters before the word "Inst" or "Institution" but not followed by the word group as part of the same word

Tags: regex

Using regular expressions, I can’t seem to get the following to work. Any set of characters before the word "**Inst**" or "**Institution**" but not followed by the word group as part of the same word. so for example I don't want to match "**m_InstitutionGroup**" but I do want "**m_Institution blah blah Group**"

Other examples:

```
Inst - include
inst - include 
institution - include
rtertInstitutionsdfdf – include
345_rtertInstitutionssdf45d454fdf – include
InstXXX555_group - exclude
Institution456eretGroup - exclude
```

I have tried:

```
inst(itution)(?!(Group))
```

Comment: Does the casing of isnt/institution matter?

Comment: BTW, for playing with regex check out http://rentzsch.github.com/JSRegexTeststand/ & http://regextester.com/

Comment: Just checking - you want to match the "m_" part, right? As per *Any set of characters before the word "Inst" or "Institution"*

Comment: thanks. The "m_" part does not need to be matched. Basically I just mean any character before inst or institution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[Ii]nst(itution)?(?!(\w*[Gg]roup))
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30r1v)

This will match `[Ii]nst` with an optional `(itution)?` following, but only if there is not `[Gg]roup` following with only `\w` characters (letters, digits and _) in between.

Answer (score 1):

This regex:

```
inst(itution)(?!(Group))
```

will only match `institution`, not `inst`, because you haven't made `itution` optional. Additonally, it will only work if `Group` **immediately** follows `institution`.

Try:

```
[Ii]nst(?:itution)?(?!\S*[Gg]roup)
```

which reads as `Inst`, `inst`, `Institution`, or `institution` followed by anything up to the next whitespace, so long as that anything does not contain the strings `group` or `Group`.

Comment: Now its better with `\S*`, depends now on the OPs requirements if he needs `\S` or `\w`.

Comment: great thanks. Can I ask one more thing? If i want "Institution/Inst blah blah group" but not "InstGroup" or InstitutionGroup what would I do? Would I add a w+ after [Ii]nst(?:itution)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to match a space between your search words:

```
\w+(?=[iI]nst(itution)?.* .*Group)
```

Note that these match the first letter being any case - ie `i` or `I` - because your attempt suggests you want this

Comment: Doesn't quite do the right thing by his test cases. There may not be an intervening space.

Comment: @Li-aungYip As I read it, there *must be* an intervening space

Answer (score 0):

```
\w*inst(itution)?\w*(?<!group)\b
```

You seem to be ignoring case so add the corresponding flag to the regex function.

[RegExr link](http://regexr.com?30r1s)

Comment: My regex is matching the wanted word and not just only "inst" or "institution" like other examples do.